# HTML form to PDF

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a Thymeleaf/HTML form which is hosted by a spring/tomcat server.

Each time the form is submitted I want to email a copy of the form to a fixed email address.

In the backend how can I get a copy of the Form Data into a HTML/Thymeleaf copy of the form before rendering to PDF?

Comment: It would be much easier to just send the data entered into the form by e-mail. Do you really need a PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Henry is right, html in the email is the way to go unless you want an immutable copy. In that case, you'd have to process the submitted form data and write it to a pdf using itext before attaching it to an email and sending it off.